# In Excel, get 'SheetN'!Cell where N is 1, 2, 3, ...?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have worksheets named "Team 1", "Team 2", etc.
Here's now I currently get my data:

```
=AVERAGE('Team 1'!D12:D14)
=AVERAGE('Team 2'!D12:D14)
=AVERAGE('Team 3'!D12:D14)
...
=AVERAGE('Team 1'!D15:D16)
=AVERAGE('Team 2'!D15:D16)
=AVERAGE('Team 3'!D15:D16)
...
```

And so on. How do I repeat this for a large number of worksheets without manually editing the `1`, `2`, `3` etc. in each formula?

Answer (score 2):

There may be a better way to do this, but I found a workaround. First I put the names of each worksheet into a series of cells:

```
Team 1
Team 2
Team 3
...
```

Then I used an `INDIRECT` reference and string concatenation:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("'"&B4&"'!"&"D16:D17"))
```

Where `B4` contains the text `Team 1`, `B5` contains `Team 2`, etc.
With this formula, everything except the `B4` is a string, so I can click-drag and Excel will auto increment it to `B5`, `B6`, and so on.

Comment: You can remove the `"&"` as from the `'!` until the end is one string. You can also do `=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("'Team "B4&"'!D16:D17"))` and have in `B4` only the number.